# Update row column using min value from next couple of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update row using next couple of rows.

I have database like

```
id   Product_number   qty   parent_id    type
1     AAAA                     null      PRODUCT
2      bbb             5        1          ITEM
3      ccc             8        1          ITEM
```

I have this type of data into table, so I want to update qty column of that row where type is PRODUCT  using min value of those rows where parent_id is id of row which has column type value PRODUCT etc

so result should be

```
id   Product_number   qty   parent_id    type
1     AAAA             5        null      PRODUCT
2      bbb             5        1          ITEM
3      ccc             8        1          ITEM
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Note that while the above is certainly minimal, it may not be representative.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
update t join
       (select parent_id, min(qty) as min_qty
        from t
        group by parent_id
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.parent_id
    set t.qty = tt.min_qty
    where t.qty is null and t.type = 'ITEM';
```